# Mostrar total de una suma en React

Tags: reactjs

Tengo la siguiente consulta. estoy haciendo una simple app en que se van agregando productos y estos (que son objetos) tienen nombre y precio. lo que intento hacer es que en donde renderizo la variable me vaya apareciendo el total de la suma al agregar un producto, en cambio lo que me aparece es: (sumando con 1)
**123..**

Es efectivo que me va sumando el valor que va apareciendo con el evento click de agregar pero me muestra no un total si no el historico de la sumatoria.

```
let i = 0;

let total = this.state.list.map((x, i) => {
 let val = parseInt(x.price);
 i += val;
 return i;   
 console.log('suma ', i); 
})

return(
  <Container>
    <Row>
      <Col sm='6'>
        <Form>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label>Producto</Label>
            <Input type='text' name='product' onChange={ e => this.getData(e) } placeholder='añade un item'></Input>
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label>Precio</Label>
            <Input type='text' name='price' onChange={ e => this.getData(e) } placeholder='añade un item'></Input>
          </FormGroup>
          <Button className='btn btn-success' onClick={ e => this.submitData(e) } >Añadir</Button>
        </Form>
      </Col>
      <Col sm='6' className='mt-4 border' style={{ overflowY: 'scroll', position: 'relative', height: '200px'}}>
      <h4>Productos {listado.length}</h4>
      <TransitionGroup>
      {listado}
      </TransitionGroup>
      </Col>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <Container className='mt-4'>
       {total} **aqui es donde me aparece el 123..en vez del total**
      </Container>
    </Row>
  </Container>

);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Errores que veo en tu código:

- Tienes `i` (que asumo es donde quieres acumular tu sumatoria) definido 2 veces, una con `let` y otra dentro de tu función anónima de `map`.
- En tu definición de `(x, i)` para `map`, [según la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map#Syntax), a `x` se le está asignando el valor actual de tu lista y para `i` el índice, lo cual no concuerda con lo que estás haciendo más tarde en la lógica de tu función.
- Lo que `map` retorna, es **una lista** con cada uno de los valores que hayas **retornado** dentro de la función callback que le pasas a `map`. Luego, como estás retornando el valor de `i` (que es el índice de tu arreglo), simplemente estás asignando a total un arreglo `[1, 2, 3]`. Lo que de verdad requieres para tu problema es [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce), donde ni siquiera necesitarías una variable acumuladora.
- Algo menor, pero tu `console.log` nunca es alcanzado, ya que haces un `return` antes de que siquiera llegue a esa línea.

Con esas indicaciones debería ser suficiente para que veas por ti mismo como resolver tu problema. Saludos

Comment: Le añado un ejemplo de como puede ser un `reduce` para complementar tu respuesta y ayudar al OP. `let total = this.state.list.reduce((obj, data) => {obj += data.price; return obj; }, 0)`

Comment: @Alter LAgos gracias por la pronta respuesta, efectivamente no estaba haciendo uso de la funcion reduce y claro mejore las variables para que no se mezclen con el parametro pasado en map.

Comment: @GermanAlzate vale estimado, si al final utilice reduce para este ejercicio, eso si al principio me salia uno de los parametros pasados en .reduce como indefinido y era porque estaba tratando de hacer reduce a los elementos de el objeto que devolvia list y no los estaba guardando en un arreglo vacio para luego recorrerlos! :D jjaja cosas de un junior